# "She herself have (or has) watched it"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> She herself have (or has) watched it.

I know the current grammar is to use 'has' but my Grammarly app recognizes no error when 'have' is used. Or is there any exception rule where using 'have' is also correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly Languagetool is becoming confused by the "She herself" grammatical subject, and isn't recognising this as third-person singular.

Languagetool is tuned to recognise the sort of errors and poor style that native speakers of English tend to make, and moreover is tuned to give relatively few false positives.  If it detects a mistake, there usually is a reason for it.  But it does miss lots of mistakes. Having no blue underlines doesn't mean your text is correct.

For what its worth,  I've just checked the following four sentences in Grammarly and it correctly identifies the error with "have" in both cases.

> She herself has watched it. She herself have watched it.

> She has watched it. She have watched it.

Comment: Ohh. The proofreader that I use is Languagetool and not Grammarly. But they are exactly similar, so I mentioned Grammarly as it is well known proofreader. Time to switch back to grammarly then.

Comment: You specify "grammarly" by name in your question.  They are clearly not exactly the same! I doubt that they share any code.  But anyway, my answer is the same just :s/Grammarly/languagetool/

Answer (score 1):

I think the word "herself" is confusing your Grammarly app (which can't always be trusted).

"Have" would be used if there were more than one person, for example:

> John and herself have watched it.

Perhaps grammarly thinks that is what you were trying to write, so it's not correcting the verb?

Why have you got the word "herself" in there anyway? We do sometimes use it that way to add emphasis, but it does sound formal, for example, "*you yourself said it*".

So, you *could* say "she herself has watched it", but it would be far more natural to say:

> She has watched it herself.

Comment: Yes. I was trying to add emphasis while having a conversation with my friend.

Comment: **John and herself have watched it!** Surely not!